# Documentation on Serving static files

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have a question about the docs for serving static files... It claims

> Static files are automatically served from the public directories of
>   the application, which can be customized with "paths" in
>   Mojolicious::Static, or one of the DATA sections from "classes" in
>   Mojolicious::Static. And if that's not enough you can also serve them
>   manually with "reply->static" in Mojolicious::Plugin::DefaultHelpers
>   and "reply->file" in Mojolicious::Plugin::DefaultHelpers.

What does it mean by automatically served from public directories and how does it differ from manually serving them?

I guess my question is -> How do you access or use the automatically served pages in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is also briefly covered in [the tutorial](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Guides::Tutorial#Static-files). Basically, before going through the dynamic routes you add with `get` and so on, it will check if the requested file path is provided in your public directories or data sections. By default the only public directory assigned is `public/` in your application root. And by default the only class whose `__DATA__` section is checked is `main` (as `__DATA__` section templates are most commonly used for Mojolicious::Lite apps in a single file script).

So as a real example, if you get a request for `/foo.txt`, it will first check if there is a `public/foo.txt` file or a `foo.txt` in the `__DATA__` section for the `main` package. If it finds one, it will be served as-is, with some optimizations for browsers that cache static files. If not, it will try to match it to the routes you have declared.

The `paths` and `classes` attributes in the Mojolicious::Static object for your application (accessible as the `static` attribute on the application) can be changed or appended during startup with other places to look.

```
push @{$app->static->paths}, $app->home->child('other');
$app->static->classes(['Some::Class']);
```